# Error while starting jboss 7

Tags: jboss7.x

I am getting following error while starting jboss 7.1

```
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
'-jar' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I have set JAVA_HOME,PATH variables properly but still getting error---
I am using jdk 1.6 and  sqljdbc4 driver

hi Frederic ,

I am pasting standalone.bat which is used to start jboss---

```
            @echo off
            rem -------------------------------------------------------------------------
            rem JBoss Bootstrap Script for Windows
            rem -------------------------------------------------------------------------

            rem $Id$

            @if not "%ECHO%" == ""  echo %ECHO%
            @if "%OS%" == "Windows_NT" setlocal

            if "%OS%" == "Windows_NT" (
              set "DIRNAME=%~dp0%"
            ) else (
              set DIRNAME=.\
            )

            rem Read an optional configuration file.
            if "x%STANDALONE_CONF%" == "x" (
               set "STANDALONE_CONF=%DIRNAME%standalone.conf.bat"
            )
            if exist "%STANDALONE_CONF%" (
               echo Calling "%STANDALONE_CONF%"
               call "%STANDALONE_CONF%" %*
            ) else (
               echo Config file not found "%STANDALONE_CONF%"
            )

            pushd %DIRNAME%..
            set "RESOLVED_JBOSS_HOME=%CD%"
            popd

            if "x%JBOSS_HOME%" == "x" (
              set "JBOSS_HOME=%RESOLVED_JBOSS_HOME%"
            )

            pushd "%JBOSS_HOME%"
            set "SANITIZED_JBOSS_HOME=%CD%"
            popd

            if "%RESOLVED_JBOSS_HOME%" NEQ "%SANITIZED_JBOSS_HOME%" (
                echo WARNING JBOSS_HOME may be pointing to a different installation - unpredictable results may occur.
            )

            set DIRNAME=

            if "%OS%" == "Windows_NT" (
              set "PROGNAME=%~nx0%"
            ) else (
              set "PROGNAME=standalone.bat"
            )

            rem Setup JBoss specific properties
            set JAVA_OPTS=-Dprogram.name=%PROGNAME% %JAVA_OPTS%

            if "x%JAVA_HOME%" == "x" (
              set  JAVA=java
              echo JAVA_HOME is not set. Unexpected results may occur.
              echo Set JAVA_HOME to the directory of your local JDK to avoid this message.
            ) else (
              set "JAVA=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java"
            )

            if not "%PRESERVE_JAVA_OPTS%" == "true" (
              rem Add -client to the JVM options, if supported (32 bit VM), and not overriden
              echo "%JAVA_OPTS%" | findstr /I \-server > nul
              if errorlevel == 1 (
                "%JAVA%" -client -version 2>&1 | findstr /I /C:"Client VM" > nul
                if not errorlevel == 1 (
                  set "JAVA_OPTS=-client %JAVA_OPTS%"
                )
              )

              rem Add compressed oops, if supported (64 bit VM), and not overriden
              echo "%JAVA_OPTS%" | findstr /I "\-XX:\-UseCompressedOops \-client" > nul
              if errorlevel == 1 (
                "%JAVA%" -XX:+UseCompressedOops -version > nul 2>&1
                if not errorlevel == 1 (
                  set "JAVA_OPTS=-XX:+UseCompressedOops %JAVA_OPTS%"
                )
              )

              rem Add tiered compilation, if supported (64 bit VM), and not overriden
              echo "%JAVA_OPTS%" | findstr /I "\-XX:\-TieredCompilation \-client" > nul
              if errorlevel == 1 (
                "%JAVA%" -XX:+TieredCompilation -version > nul 2>&1
                if not errorlevel == 1 (
                  set "JAVA_OPTS=-XX:+TieredCompilation %JAVA_OPTS%"
                )
              )
            )

            rem Find jboss-modules.jar, or we can't continue
            if exist "%JBOSS_HOME%\jboss-modules.jar" (
                set "RUNJAR=%JBOSS_HOME%\jboss-modules.jar"
            ) else (
              echo Could not locate "%JBOSS_HOME%\jboss-modules.jar".
              echo Please check that you are in the bin directory when running this script.
              goto END
            )

            rem Setup JBoss specific properties

            rem Setup the java endorsed dirs
            set JBOSS_ENDORSED_DIRS=%JBOSS_HOME%\lib\endorsed

            rem Set default module root paths
            if "x%JBOSS_MODULEPATH%" == "x" (
              set  "JBOSS_MODULEPATH=%JBOSS_HOME%\modules"
            )

            rem Set the standalone base dir
            if "x%JBOSS_BASE_DIR%" == "x" (
              set  "JBOSS_BASE_DIR=%JBOSS_HOME%\standalone"
            )
            rem Set the standalone log dir
            if "x%JBOSS_LOG_DIR%" == "x" (
              set  "JBOSS_LOG_DIR=%JBOSS_BASE_DIR%\log"
            )
            rem Set the standalone configuration dir
            if "x%JBOSS_CONFIG_DIR%" == "x" (
              set  "JBOSS_CONFIG_DIR=%JBOSS_BASE_DIR%/configuration"
            )
            rem Set memory configuration
            set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xms512M -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.timezone=GMT"

            echo ===============================================================================
            echo.
            echo   JBoss Bootstrap Environment
            echo.
            echo   JBOSS_HOME: %JBOSS_HOME%
            echo.
            echo   JAVA: %JAVA%
            echo.
            echo   JAVA_OPTS: %JAVA_OPTS%
            echo.
            echo ===============================================================================
            echo.

            :RESTART
            "%JAVA%" %JAVA_OPTS% ^

             "-Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=%JBOSS_LOG_DIR%\boot.log" ^

             "-Dlogging.configuration=file:%JBOSS_CONFIG_DIR%/logging.properties" ^

                -jar "%JBOSS_HOME%\jboss-modules.jar" ^
                -mp "%JBOSS_MODULEPATH%" ^
                -jaxpmodule "javax.xml.jaxp-provider" ^
                 org.jboss.as.standalone ^
                -Djboss.home.dir="%JBOSS_HOME%" ^
                 %*

            if ERRORLEVEL 10 goto RESTART

            :END
            if "x%NOPAUSE%" == "x" pause

            :END_NO_PAUSE
```

Comment: copy paste the script that you use to start

Comment: Here how to copy paste the script--Its too long

Comment: hi Frederic,I have paste starting script by edting question above...Please response back with suggestions

Comment: please anyone can solve my problem please....?